# In NEKOGAMES' "Parameters", what is RCV?

Tags: parameters

In [Nekogames' *Parameters*](http://www.nekogames.jp/g.html?gid=PRM) there are various stats. All the other stats I have figured out (DEFis defence, ATK is attack) but I have no idea what RCV is. My best guess is it increases the chances of what you receive? Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RCV is "Recover", and governs how quickly ACT (Action) and LIFE fill back up.

Comment: And here I was thinking it was "Receive". Thanks!